# Postgresql: Selecting from list of substrings

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm really beginner in Postgresql and I'm currently facing a bit of issue in retrieving data.

I have table with these structures

```
url (text)    | tags (varchar)      | content (text)
some.url.com  | {'news', 'local'}   | 'some content a'
anotherweb.com| {'news', 'headline'}| 'some content b'
isit.web.co   | {'local', 'weather'}| 'some content c'
```

With DDL as in

```
CREATE TABLE news (
    link text NULL,
    tags varchar[] NULL,
    "content" text NULL)
```

PS: This DDL is extracted from DBeaver DDL tab of the table. After checking on database schema, the tags field has data type of 'ARRAY'

I'm trying to retrieve data from this table where the tag contains any from list of substrings that I provide eg. in Python we can write this if expression as

```
if any(subtr in tags for subtr in [list_of_substrings]):
   # do this
```

I've found a similar one in Postgres, which is [`IN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/). But I haven't found anyone using it with substrings. The current solution I can find is using [`LIKE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-like/) with regex (for pattern matching with the substring) but it would ended up with long condition statement like

```
WHERE tags like '%substr1%' OR
      tags like '%substr2%' OR
      ...
```

Is there an alternative to the current solution I got?

Comment: What data type is `tags` exactly? `varchar` or an array, e.g. `varchar[]`? Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement (as formatted text, no screen shots please) .

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i've added it, tho I'm accessing the database thru DBeaver

Answer (score 1):

Your tags column is an array of varchar as you want to check each element, you need to unnest the array:

```
select n.*
from news n
where exists (select *
              from unnest(n.tags) as x(tag)
              where x.tag like '%substr1%'
                 or x.tag like '%substr2%')
```

Comment: What if i'm having lots (say > 10) substrings to add as condition? I'm trying to avoid using LIKE after considering this possibility

Comment: Well, the use of LIKE is the core of your question. If you want a partial match on the value, there is no other way